# Eclipse setup with Oracle JDBC

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm trying to setup eclipse to work with JDBC. I have installed the Oracle express database, and started it. Connecting to the database through the SQL command line works.

When I try to setup the connection in eclipse, and I press "Test Connection", I get a "Ping failed" error message. I think I'm using the correct JDBC version (11.2.0.2, version number found from SQL command line window), downloaded from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html). The service name is set to `xe` and the host is set to `localhost`, port to `1521`. The username and password are the same that I use in the SQL command line.

Any idea what the problem is? I'm on Linux, if relevant.

Comment: how about the port?

Comment: @user3808887 I'm using the default 1521 in eclipse, but I'm not sure how to find out if the DB is running on that port.

Comment: do u have the oracle client? if so you can check it from there whether the db is running or not by clicking the Test Connection button

Comment: No I don't have a GUI client, but I think it's running because I can connect to it on the SQL command line. It accepts the username and password and connects.